# Rotating map with directions displayed

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I am getting google directions and displaying them on a V2 Mapview. So the resulting map displayed a start point, end point, and the route between them. I add them to the map as follows:

```
LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
mapView.animateCamera(cu);
```

I would now like the map rotated so that the start and end point are on the same horizontal plane. The map displays a different route each time, so I need logic to calculate how many degrees the rotation needs to be, and code to actually rotate the map, within the specified bounds as in the code above. I'm struggling to find a way of doing this.

Comment: basically you want your map should rotate as you walk or drive through the path between two locations??

Comment: No, I just want the route displayed in the horizontal plane once only. The directions don't get followed after this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this, i implemented that some time ago. (If u dont want to have the Tilt effect) - just set it to Zero)

```
targetBearing = destinationLocation.bearingTo(myCurrentLocation);
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(latitudeCurrentLocation,
                    longitudeCurrentLocation)).bearing(targetBearing + 530)
            .tilt(67).zoom(15).build();

    map.animateCamera(
            CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition), 5000,
            null);
```

EDIT: `bearing(targetBearing + 530)` this does the rotation in degrees.

Comment: Thank you, the bearingTo() method is useful here. The issue I have is combining my code (where the animateCamera method takes a CameraUpdate object) with your code (where the animateCamera method takes a CameraPosition object). I need the CameraUpdate object as this contains the bounds which is crucial to my requirements.

Comment: Ok it's fine, I need to apply your code after my code has completed, by checking onCameraChangedListener. Then I take the values from the current map, and apply them to the CameraPosition.Builder() method. Thanks!

Comment: why added 530 here?